# Is lease_tasks() in gae pull queues a blocking method?

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue, pull-queue

I have a pull-queue in Google App Engine and a resident backend which processes the tasks in the pull queue. The backend has several worker threads for consuming and processing tasks, as suggested in a post in Google Cloud Platform blog

https://cloud.google.com/resources/articles/ios-push-notifications

Workers poll the pull-queue with lease_tasks(). My question is: is lease_tasks() supposed to be a blocking method, i.e. block the current thread's execution until either the queue has some tasks or a deadline is exceeded?

According to the GAE documentation

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-pull#Python_Leasing_tasks

lease_tasks() accepts a 'deadline' parameter and may raise the DeadlineExceededError, thus isn't rational to assume that lease_tasks() blocks up to 'deadline' seconds?

The problem is that while I 'm developing the application in the development server, lease_tasks() returns immediately with an empty list of tasks. The result is that  the worker thread's while-loop is constantly calling lease_tasks(), thus consuming 100% of CPU. If I put an explicit sleep(), say for 5 sec, that will make the worker go to sleep and won't wake up if a task is placed in the queue in the mean time. That would make the worker less responsive (worst case, it might take ->5 secs for handling the next task), plus I would consume more CPU (wake up->sleep cycles) than just having the thread block in a 'queue' (I know the pull-queue is actually an RPC, yet it abstractly remains a producer queue)

Perhaps this happens only with the dev app server while in GAE lease_tasks() blocks. However, the example code from the blog post mentioned above also suspends thread execution with sleep(). The example code is available in github and a link is in the blog post (unfortunately I cannot post it here)

Answer (score 0):

`lease_tasks` does not wait for new tasks to be added. Most task queue calls take up to 5 seconds. The calls to lease tasks and to fetch queue statistics take longer - up to 10 seconds by default.

Most users won't need to set the deadline, it is an optional parameter. If you have very many workers contending on the same queue and often experience transient errors after 10 seconds, consider increasing the lease deadline to 20 seconds (or shard the load over more queues and/or tags). Alternately, if you only have one worker and it always needs time to perform other work in addition to leasing tasks, a small deadline like 5 seconds could be used, but it is much better to use the async API instead.